# What is the condition of a product if it hasn’t been unboxed?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

In my mother language, if a product is unused when we buy it, we use the term “0” (zero). What would the corresponding German term be for a product in its original state? Is “0” (*null*) a valid term?

Comment: If a product hasn't been unpacked yet, it is called `Originalverpackt`. For the rest of the question it is still not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: In the way the question is reduced atm, this would be *Originalverpackt* as @raznagul said. It’s still not the clearest but I seem to be understanding.

Comment: In ungeöffneter Originalverpackung - not just original packaging, but unopened as well.

Comment: For the record, it‘s common to see _originalverpackt_ or _Originalverpackung_ being abbreviated as _OVP_.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon has a guide for the description of second hand products, called [Leitfaden für Zustandsangaben](http://www.amazon.de/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=3366851). They have special guides for *books, music, videos and dvds, video- and computer games, software, electronics for entertainent, stuff for the kitchen, house and garden, as well as toys.*

The categories are

- neu (new),
- B-Ware & 2. Wahl (erneuert) (second choice; repaired by a professional, with garanty and as good as new)
- gebraucht - wie neu (used, but like new, never used before)
- gebraucht - sehr gut (used, but excellent condition)
- gebraucht - gut (used, but good)
- gebraucht - akzeptabel (used, with damages, but still readable)
- Sammlerstück (stuff that is rar, not producted anymore or signed, should be described with the catagories about)

Cited here the first part of the Leitfaden für Zustandsangaben about books (as you can see it is very detailed):

> Bücher in einem anderen als neuen Zustand müssen - sofern es sich
> nicht um Sammlerstücke handelt - als gebraucht angeboten werden. Als
> Unterkategorien können Sie zwischen "wie neu", "sehr gut", "gut" und
> "akzeptabel" wählen.
>
> **Wie neu:** Ungelesene Ausgabe in Topzustand. Schutzumschlag ist unbeschädigt. Seiten sind sauber und weisen weder Notizen noch Knicke
> irgendwelcher Art auf. Es kann sich bei der Ausgabe um ein sogenanntes
> Mängelexemplar handeln. Ist dies der Fall, befindet sich eine
> entsprechende Markierung in der Regel auf der Unterkante des Buches,
> in einigen Fällen auch auf der Außen- oder Rückseite. Wenn Sie
> Mängelexemplare bei Amazon.de Marketplace verkaufen, sollten Sie unter
> "Anmerkung zum Zustand" nicht nur erwähnen, dass es sich um ein
> Mängelexemplar handelt, sondern auch angeben, an welcher Stelle das
> Buch mit dem Markierungszeichen als Mängelexemplar versehen wurde.
>
> **Sehr gut:** Gelesene Ausgabe in hervorragendem Zustand. Seiten sind intakt und weisen weder Notizen noch Unterstreichungen auf. Der
> Buchrücken zeigt keinerlei Knicke oder andere Gebrauchsspuren.
>
> **Gut:** Gelesene Ausgabe in gutem, sauberen Zustand. Seiten und Einband sind intakt (ebenfalls der Schutzumschlag, falls vorhanden).
> Buchrücken darf Gebrauchsspuren aufweisen. Notizen oder
> Unterstreichungen in begrenztem Ausmaß sowie Bibliotheksstempel sind
> zumutbar.
>
> **Akzeptabel:** Ausgabe ist in akzeptablem, lesbaren Zustand. Seiten und Einband sind intakt (Schutzumschlag darf fehlen). Notizen und
> Unterstreichungen in größerem Ausmaß -- Kugelschreiber oder Textmarker
> -- sind zulässig. Der Text muss allerdings vollständig lesbar sein.
>
> **Inakzeptabel:** und damit nicht zum Verkauf auf Amazon.de Marketplace
> zugelassen, sind angeschimmelte, befleckte oder anders verschmutzte
> Ausgaben. Ebenso Ausgaben mit fehlenden Seiten oder unlesbarem Text.
>
> Rein zu Werbezwecken vertriebene Bücher sowie Vorabausgaben und
> Leseexemplare dürfen aus rechtlichen Gründen nicht angeboten werden.
> Als Sammlerstück gelten Bücher, die entweder signiert, nicht mehr
> lieferbar oder aus sonstigen Gründen rar sind. Zur näheren
> Beschreibung stehen Ihnen die gleichen Unterkategorien wie bei
> gebrauchten Büchern zur Verfügung. Des Weiteren sollten Sie unter
> "Anmerkung zum Zustand" näher erläutern, warum es sich bei Ihrem Buch
> um ein Sammlerstück handelt.

Comment: It's highly enough Iris,and if a car not drived is it "0 km" or "neu"?

Comment: Amazon has no section about cars ;) A new car has always 0 km, but as soon as drive it around a block to test it, it is not  new anymore. That's the reason why you can buy testcars/ cars that were used for presentations cheeper even

Answer (score 1):

To give you an answer from outside of the Amazon recommendations it is widely understood that a product is

### Neu

if it was new, unused, and comes in the original state. If not further elaborated (see below) we can also epect it to come in the untouched original packaging. This is also true for a car but then we usually use the term

- **Neuwagen** which is also [legally defined](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuwagen).

In case we want to further stress that an article is brand-new we can alternatively say it is

- **fabrikneu**.

When it comes to the condition of the packaging it is a bit more complicated because even used to very used products are being sold in the original packaging (***in** Originalverpackung*). If we want to explicitely say the the package was not opened we do that by using

- **Neu in ungeöffneter Originalverpackung.**

If *ungeöffnet* was left out we can almost be sure that it was opened and a package seal may be broken (but the product was not used, because it still says *neu*) If a product was never used but the original packaging was opened not included we would say

- **Neu [und unbenutzt] ohne Originalverpackung**

Anything else would mean the article was used its condition should further be specified with *neuwertig* or *wie neu* coming close to new. As soon as a used article is *fast neu* only we can expect at least some traces of usage. For a car the meaning of *unbenutzt* can also mean that though newer used production time was more than a year ago, which would then not classify this car as being a *Neuwagen*.

When buying be careful with the term *Originalverpackung* because this can also refer to the package only, i.e. without content. The missing little preposition ***in*** (see above) can make a huge difference:

> **iPhone 6** Originalverpackung, nur 1 mal geöffnet ab € 1,- zu versteigern.

There are reports of people who bought such an empty box on Ebay.

Answer (score -1):

"If it hasn’t been unboxed" could mean in German "ori­gi­nal­ver­packt und ungeöffnet".